# ODEs explosion times

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was interested in the concept of solutions to 1-D ODEs "exploding", i.e., diverging to $\infty$ in a finite time, and came across this interesting paper on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1843.pdf

In the introductory paragraph, the authors consider the following IVP:

$$ 
\begin{matrix}
y'(t) = b [y(t)], \quad t > 0, \\
y(0) = x_{0}
\end{matrix}
$$

They claim that for $b > 0$, Osgood's test says that solutions to this ODE explode iff:

$$\int_{x_{0}}^{\infty} \frac{ds}{b(s)} < \infty$$. 
My first question is where do these limits of integration come from?

Second, as an example, for my own interest I tried analyzing the following ODE problem, (Which I just made up!)

$$x'[t] = \sqrt{1-x[t]^2}, \quad x[0] = a$$
My issue is that the RHS is only positive-definite for $-1 < x < 1$. Would the Osgood test integral in this case be

$$\int_{x_{0}}^{1} \frac{ds}{1-s^2}$$
or still
$$\int_{x_{0}}^{\infty} \frac{ds}{1-s^2}$$?

Solving the ODE itself using integrating factors, as an aside, I got:

$$x[t] = \sin[t+ ArcSin[a]],$$ 
which doesn't explode for $-1 < a < 1$.

I then tried comparing this result to which integral expression is correct. For the improper integral, I get that
$$\int_{x_{0}}^{\infty} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^2}} = -\infty$$, 
but for the proper definite integral I get:
$$\int_{x_{0}}^{1} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^2}} = ArcCos[a] < \infty$$
So, comparing to the actual solution, it seems like the improper integral which is what the authors of the paper claim is correct, but I don't know why they have infinity in their integral limits!

Any ideas?
Thanks.
Thomas

Comment: $b(s)$ is the growth rate of $s$, i.e, $\dot{s}$.  The integral $\int_{x_{0}}^{\infty} \frac{ds}{b(s)}$ is then merely the value of the parameter $t$ when $y$ diverges to $\infty$, starting from the initial value $x_0$.

Comment: Also note that the article assumes that $b(y)$ is a positive real valued function defined on $[0, \infty)$. Your example $b(y) = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ isn't quite the same.

Comment: @Weeam I understand, but, would the computations differ that much? I think if you just restrict $x_0$ to be from -1 to 1, ie., where b(y) is positive, then, maybe it would be the same thing?

Comment: @ThomasMoore The assumption is used in the proof. The point is, you're interested in how $y(t)$ diverges to $\infty$ in finite time, yet in $y' = b(y(t))$ you only allow $y$ to range from $-1$ to $1$ by your choice of $b$, so it doesn't look like a trivial assumption!

Comment: When solving $x'=b(x)$ starting from $x(0)=a$ for some function $b$ such that $b>0$ on $[a,a^*)$ and $b(a^*)=0$, the test becomes whether $$\int_a^{a^*}\frac{du}{b(u)}$$ converges or not. If $b(u)=\sqrt{1-u^2}$ and $|a|<1$ then $a^*=1$ and the integral converges hence the solutions are such that $x(t)\to1$ in finite time. Note finally that $x(t)=\sin(t+\arcsin(a))$ solves the differential equation *only on some finite time interval around $0$*, namely, only for $t_i(a)<t<t_f(a)$ with $t_i(a)=-(\pi/2)-\arcsin(a)$ and $t_f(a)=(\pi/2)-\arcsin(a)$.